# multiple date picker to jquery variable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dom

I searched the whole web, and i can't get things to work!

I use this http://arca-computing.github.io/MultipleDatePicker/ code, and the basic outcome is {{pickedDays}}, an angular element. I can display the selected days without a problem:

```
<span style="float:none; margin: 5px; position: relative" ng-repeat="x in pickedDays | orderBy : sortComment : true .reverse()">
    {{x.locale("de").format('Do MMMM')}}
</span>
```

I want to do calculations now, so i want to transfer them to a jquery variable:

var arrayDates = [];
arrayDates = {{pickedDays}};

This obviously does not work.. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried $scope.pickedDays. since you have used it.

Comment: Yes, i did:        $(document).on("click", "#abc", function (e) {
            alert(document.getElementById("thetext").innerHTML);
            alert($scope.pickedDays);
        }); i receive only one alert for the first getElementById, showing "thetext" inner html proberly!

Comment: Is it possible for you create js fiddle ?

Comment: Not that easy, because angular and all its components are widely scattered.. =/ maybe http://arca-computing.github.io/MultipleDatePicker/ helps, i don't know

Comment: i need another way to access {{picked Days}}, as thr simple assignment array = {{pickedDays}} obviously doesn't work..

Comment: are you using this for Angularjs or Angular?